# How i can migrate my getPrime() method so it only returns me prime number but not ()

Tags: scala

Problem : I just want to call `getPrime(100)` and return only the prime numbers and I don't want use `collect`.

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
  getPrime(100).collect{
    case i:Int => println(i);
  }
}
```

Here I want to change something

```
def getPrime(range : Int) = {
  Range(2,range).map(x => if(isPrime(x)) x);
}

def isPrime(no : Int) = !Range(2,Math.sqrt(no).toInt + 1).exists(x => no%x ==0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has [already been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624522/how-to-get-first-100-prime-numbers-in-scala-as-i-got-result-but-it-dispays-blank/49624998#49624998), you don't want to use `if` without an `else`, and you shouldn't use `map()` when what you need is `filter()`

```
def getPrime(range: Int): Seq[Int] =
  Range(2,range).filter(isPrime)
```

---

`isPrime()` can also be expressed a little more directly.

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean =
  2 to Math.sqrt(n).toInt forall(n%_ > 0)
```

Comment: **thanks** for your suggestion and help to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your getPrime method is returning AnyVal. You can use collect there to return only collection of int.

```
    scala> def getPrime(range : Int) = {
     |       Range(2,range).map(x => if(isPrime(x)) x).collect{
     | case e:Int => e
     |   }
     | }
getPrime: (range: Int)scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]

scala> getPrime(100)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97)
```

Comment: **thanks** for your reply but it's showing me error as **can not resolve reference collect with such signature**

Comment: It is working on repl. Please check you have not done any mistake.

Comment: oops it's my mistake and misplaced () with {}

Comment: No problem. it happens. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `collect`, you can use `isInstanceOf` to filter out only `Int` values,

```
def getPrime(range: Int) = {
      Range(2, range).map(x => if (isPrime(x)) x).filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another great way to generate prime numbers would be to use streams.

Consider the following

```
def naturals(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: naturals(n + 1)
def primes(s: Stream[Int] = naturals(2)): Stream[Int] = s.head #:: primes(s.tail.filter(_ % s.head > 0))
```

That's it. You have a very elegant functional prime number generator.

If you want the first `100` prime numbers as a list

```
primes().take(100).toList
```

Or if you are interested only in the 100th prime number

```
primes().drop(99).head
```

This was the example that sold me on the usefulness of streams !

Comment: **thanks** for your reply but i just started leaning Scala and your code looks quit tricky